# Convert image to tensor with range [0,255] instead of [0,1]?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use transforms.compose to convert my images into normalized images with a range of [0,255] instead of normalizing it as [0,1] for training my model. How do I make my code do this. Currently it normalizes the images from [0,1]. How would i just multiply this up to 255 to make it 0-255 or is it not that simple?

```
def build_model(self):
        """ DataLoader """
        train_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.Resize((self.img_size + 30, self.img_size+30)),
            transforms.RandomCrop(self.img_size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
        ])
        test_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((self.img_size, self.img_size)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would **normalize** values between `[0, 1]` then **standardize** by calculating the `mean` and `std` of your whole training set and apply it to all datasets (training, validation and test set).

The following is essentially a `x in [x_min, x_max] -> x' in [0, 1]` mapping:

```
x_min, x_max = x.min(), x.max()
x = (x - x_min) / (x_max-x_min)
```

Then **standardize**, for instance with the z-score, which makes `mean(x')=0` and `std(x')=1`:

```
mean, std = x.mean(), x.std()
x = (x - mean) / std
```

---

Back to your question, [`torchvision.transforms.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize) is described as:

```
output[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]
```

If you divide your `std` argument by *255* then you will end multiply by *255* the output.

Here's an exemple with shape `(b=1, c=3, h=1, w=3)`:

```
> x = torch.tensor([[[[0.2, 0.3, 0.6]], [[0.1, 0.4, 0.2]], [[0.1, 0.8, 0.6]]]])

> mean, std = x.mean(), x.std()
tensor(0.3667), tensor(0.2500)

> t = T.Normalize(mean=mean, std=std/255)

> t(x).mean(), t(x).std()
tensor(~0), tensor(255.)
```

However, if you're just looking to multiply your data by *255* inside the `torchvision.transforms.Compose` pipeline you can just do:

```
T.Compose([
    # other transforms
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize(mean=(0,)*3, std=(255,)*3)
])
```

Or with just a lambda:

```
T.Compose([
    # other transforms
    T.ToTensor(),
    lambda x: x*255
])
```

---

*Having imported `torchvision.transforms` as `T`.*

Comment: I tried adding `transforms.Normalize(mean=(0,)*3, std=(255,)*3)` after `transforms.ToTensor()` but it just outputs black images now. I'm trying to do all this in the Compose function because I really don't know where to put all that other code (it's a big model that I didn't write with lots of scripts and I'm not experienced at this).

Comment: May I ask, why are you trying to get in the [0, 255] range in the first place?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get the ML model to run in Snapchat, which feeds the image into the model as [0,255] so I think I have to train it with images like that. https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/guides/machine-learning/ml-component/ml-component-overview/

Comment: Did you check your inputs where in [0, 255] after applying the transforms and before calling the model?

Comment: I'm unsure how I would check that. I apologize for my lack of skills I'm just starting out.

Comment: I noticed when it ouputs to an image file it multiplies by 255 and I got rid of that because it should be going in as 255. I think maybe the problem is that `transforms.ToTensor()` converts it to 0,1 when I want a tensor that's 0,255

Comment: That's right [`T.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) will map a [0, 255] PIL.Image to a [0, 1] torch.tensor.

Comment: How would I map a PIL.Image to a [0,255] torch tensor in the transforms.Compose function if that is at all possible. Then maybe I can normalize that using all the proper standard deviations and means and such that were calculated from the dataset?

Comment: You can define your own transform as a function. Here using a lambda: add this as the last transformation in your `T.Compose`: `lambda x: x*255`. I have edited the last part of my answer so you can see it being use in the `T.Compose`.

Comment: Thank you! The results are kind of weird so I think I'll wait on doing this job for a while until I get the model to run in lens studio.

Answer (score 1):

### First Option

I noticed you can achieve the conversion without normalization when you don't use `ToTensor` and do the conversion over numpy instead. Then the resulting tensor will not be normalized at all.

My examples are using the `pillow`. When converting to image again go with numpy again and don't use `ToPilImage` as well.

So:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('image.jpg')
im_arr = np.array(image)
# optional type conversion
im_arr = im_arr.astype(np.float32)
image_tensor = torch.tensor(image).unsqueeze_(0)

# do stuff with your image

img_np_arr = np.array(image_tensor_conv2d.squeeze_(0))
valid_pil_image = Image.fromarray(img_np_arr).convert('RGB')
valid_pil_image.save('image_torch.jpg')
```

will do the job as well.

As composer you could write like

```py
image_transform = transfroms.Compose([
          transforms.Lambda(lambda image: torch.tensor(numpy.array(image).astype(numpy.float32)).unsqueeze(0)),
          transforms.Normalize((value,), (value,))
)]
```

See [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pil-image-to-floattensor-uint16-to-float32/54577/1) for reference

### Second Option

Another option would be to use `PilToTensor` instead. Check https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.PILToTensor.html